# how to discover android devices infomation in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

When a PC connects to an Android device via USB, the device's information can be found on chrome://inspect. How can I get this information in a Chrome extension？

Comment: Are you aware that chrome extension is not supported on Android Chrome version?

Answer (score 1):

That information isn't available in the Chrome Apps/Extensions API. You should file a feature request at crbug.com explaining your use case.

If you write a Chrome App, you'll have access to the chrome.usb API, where you can connect to specific devices. See Spark's ADB functionality for an example: https://github.com/dart-lang/spark.